# Is there just one "Exit immigration" or do I choose a line/booth depending on my destination?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, destinations

Do exit immigration officials know the country people in the queue are heading to or not, or it depends on the country and/or how the airport is organised?

For example if I want to leave the country, in order to arrive at the gate, do I have to choose a particular slot to be checked my passport at or I can choose whichever is open?

Comment: The answer to this question will depend highly on a) which country b) their own citizens ; other nationals (or both). Therefore no general answer can be given.

Comment: What about western countries?

Comment: There many different western countries. Some don't care, some are very nosey others collect all possible information in case it may be useful in the future.

Comment: What about the EU and Canada?

Comment: In my experience the entire exit immigration setup is located in a way that applies it only to certain destinations. Eg "all the flights to non schengen countries leave from the east end of the terminal, and you pass exit immigration to reach that end of the terminal." People going elsewhere don't go through it.

Comment: Yes but I'm asking about the same category or group. If someone wants to go to the US from whenever in Europe (assuming he's not an EEA national), he has to take the "all passports" line. Now, do they have to choose, among those available, one in particular or they can choose whichever?

Comment: Without including the country you are exiting, and probably even the airport you are traveling from, this question is far too broad to be answerable.

Comment: For the EU in general: for EU citizens (and residents) they only check the citizenship/residence status ; for others: if the conditions of the short-term stay were fulfilled (passport stamps). They don't care where the person is going.

Comment: The available options are: (a) there is no exit passport control (either because the country does not perform any such controls, like the US or UK, or because you are heading to another country within the same visa/immigration area, like from  one Schengen country to another) or (b) there is passport control. In case (b) there are sometimes two options, based on the traveller being a national of the **departure** country or visa area (like EU/EEA/Switzerland). I’m not aware of any distinction based on the destination, but of course, there are so many combinations…

Comment: I really don’t understand why this question was closed or how it is unclear…

Comment: @jcaron It was closed **because** there are so many combinations. I could give an answer for the EU, but not for Canada. The question needs more focus. That is why it was closed.

Answer (score 1):

At the airport I use the queue is divided into 'Selected passports' and 'All passports'. And as far as I remember the 'selected passports' used to be Schengen countries only but is now wider and uses mostly automated passport gates.

But that leaves everybody to use the 'all passports' as not everybody can use the automated gates and some people chose to stay with a travel companion who can not use the gates even when they themselves can.

Everybody is processed as soon as they arrive in the secure area of the airport, so all people are mixed.

I have not used the exit immigration in other countries in a long while but as far as I understand they all allow everybody to use the 'all passports' but some may process the passengers per flight, especially if the airport does not have many flights out of the country or area.

Mostly information regarding the country you go to is collected and checked by the airline, not by exit immigration, those mostly check you were within the limits of your visa and whether there is a 'do not let this person leave the country' order.
So the country you leave is not interested in where you are going.
The airlines may share the information also with the departure country, which is much more common than getting the information from departing passengers at a passport check. But the officer will usually ask or read it on your boarding pass.

Comment: I was not asking how the queues are divided for people, but whether people were forwarded in terms of the destination or not

Comment: As you can see from the fact that everybody in that airport is processed as soon as they arrive, they are not divided into destination groups and the names of the groups that are processed confirms that. But other airports may do it different.

Comment: It is obvious that they have to be processed, immigration is there for a reason, but I wanted to know whether people have to go to a specific slot depending on where they go (in case all of them are open) or not. As for how they are divided, it's another story.

Comment: The arrangment will also in the Schengen area depend very much on the layout of the specific airport. Some airports, in particular smaller ones, are not clearly separated into national/Schengen and Non-Schengen areas, but do the exit immigration directly at the gate, if a Non-Schengen flight is about to depart from there. In those cases, the exit immigration queue is depending on where you are heading.

Comment: @user sometimes there are different passport control areas for different terminals or different sets of gates.  The gate for your flight might depend on the destination.  In that sense, it could be said that there is a relationship, at least an indirect one, between your destination and the passport control area you must use.  But a traveler never has to think about it like that.  From the traveler's viewpoint, you follow the sign directing you to your departure gate, and at some point you encounter passport control.  Then you pick an appropriate line based on the passport you are using.

Comment: I know that gates can be divided according to the type of flight (GCC, EU/Schengen), but my question was different. Given the same group of exit immigration booths, can we choose randomly one among those open or do we have to stick to one in particular?

Comment: @user, as said, that is impossible to predict as it differs per airport, some have very free choice, others will allow you one officer only. And some times everybody is seen by just one officer.

Comment: @user "Given the same group of exit immigration booths, can we choose randomly one among those open or do we have to stick to one in particular?" That is a more specific question and therefore easier to answer. You can choose whatever booth you want, subject, of course, to any restrictions that might be indicated. It is as you know standard to reserve some booths for EU/EEA/Swiss passports. One could imagine some nonstandard division, such as people with or without EU COVID certificates. It's plausible that they would make some _ad hoc_ distinction based on destination, but I've never seen it.